# SFX in Lubuntu Linux

Tags: lubuntu

does anybody know weather you can add Startup/error/hardware insert/hardware error/hardware eject/shutdown/login/logoff sounds to Linux on *Lubuntu*?

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu?

Comment: I have login sounds on my now modern Lubuntu (using LXQt), and did so with legacy Lubuntu (ie. LXDE), as KGIII mentioned, we currently don't know what you're using so can't offer any guidance.... If you're talking about modern Lubuntu, you can see autostart functions in the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html?highlight=autostart  `paplay` can be used to use pulse-audio to play a sound...  (*other events would need more that I provided*)